# Eliminate rows in a dataframe as of a condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataFrame with 3 columns. I want to eliminate rows according to a condition provided in a list that affects to information in column 2.

For example:

```
filter = ['rainy', 'sunny']

col.1 col.2 col.3
1 rainy 100
2 cloudy 50 
3 sunny 30
4 cloudy 40
5 windy 20
```

I would like to eliminate the rows containing the words in the list called filter, how could I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

**Method 1:**

```
newdf = df.query("col.2 not in @rainy").reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Method 2:**

```
newdf = df[~df["col.2"].isin(rainy)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col.1':[1,2,3,4,5],
'col.2':['rainy','cloudy','sunny','cloudy','windy'],
'col.3':[100,50,30,40,20]})

F = ['rainy', 'sunny']                                                 
df = df.iloc[[not i in F for i in df['col.2']]]
```

Comment: And if I had more than one condition? in other words, if I had: F= ['rainy'], J = ['sunny']

Comment: you mean not in F and not in J ? you can join two list like ['rainy'] + ['sunny']